# How to fix firefile.cc not downloading anything anywhere?

Tags: download

I'm trying to download a file on firefile.cc but it doesn't download (the button works and I get the "do you want a notification once it's done" message but it won't start downloading).

I tried with private navigation, I tried resetting the cookies and the cache, I tried disabling the extensions (even if none have access to firefile.cc), I tried giving the website all authorizations, I tried changing browser, I tried coming back at another time, I tried downloading things from other websites (worked), I tried changing the network I'm on, I tried other files but none worked, I tried changing OS (same computer), I tried disabling antivirus AND firewall entirely, I tried making an account but I wouldn't receive the verification email

I hided the specific hash as changing the file does not solve the issue and there might be private information

<...> are always all the same "hashes=...&shareable_link=..."

Don't say it's the download or website that's broken (error 500) because other people CAN download it

```
[Deprecation]The keyword 'push-button' specified to an 'appearance' property is not standardized. It will be removed in the future.
zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:3372 
        
        
        GET https://firefile.cc/secure/uploads/downloadChunk?<...> 500 (Internal Server Error)

E @ zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:3372
t.scheduleTask @ zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:410
e.scheduleTask @ zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:238
e.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:261
s @ zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1194
(anonymous) @ zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:3405
O.i.<computed> @ zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1518
(anonymous) @ http.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1792
t._trySubscribe @ Observable.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:43
t.subscribe @ Observable.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:29
l @ subscribeToResult.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:13
n._innerSub @ mergeMap.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:74
n._tryNext @ mergeMap.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:68
n._next @ mergeMap.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:51
n.next @ Subscriber.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:53
(anonymous) @ subscribeToArray.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:5
t._trySubscribe @ Observable.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:43
t.subscribe @ Observable.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:29
t.call @ mergeMap.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:29
t.subscribe @ Observable.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:24
(anonymous) @ download-api.service.ts:211
e @ zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:931
t.getFileMetadata @ download-api.service.ts:210
(anonymous) @ download-api.service.ts:60
(anonymous) @ download-api.service.ts.pre-build-optimizer.js:31
(anonymous) @ download-api.service.ts.pre-build-optimizer.js:12
(anonymous) @ download-api.service.ts.pre-build-optimizer.js:6
e @ zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:931
c @ download-api.service.ts.pre-build-optimizer.js:2
t.download @ download-api.service.ts.pre-build-optimizer.js:67
(anonymous) @ download-api.service.ts:45
t._trySubscribe @ Observable.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:43
t.subscribe @ Observable.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:29
t.call @ takeUntil.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:17
t.subscribe @ Observable.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:24
t.call @ tap.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:18
t.subscribe @ Observable.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:24
t.call @ filter.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:15
t.subscribe @ Observable.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:24
t.call @ map.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:18
t.subscribe @ Observable.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:24
t.call @ catchError.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:18
t.subscribe @ Observable.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:24
t.call @ map.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:18
t.subscribe @ Observable.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:24
a @ forkJoin.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:42
(anonymous) @ forkJoin.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:65
t._trySubscribe @ Observable.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:43
t.subscribe @ Observable.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:29
t.call @ map.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:18
t.subscribe @ Observable.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:24
t.call @ defaultIfEmpty.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:15
t.subscribe @ Observable.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:24
t.call @ catchError.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:18
t.subscribe @ Observable.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:24
l @ subscribeToResult.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:13
n._innerSub @ mergeMap.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:74
n._tryNext @ mergeMap.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:68
n._next @ mergeMap.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:51
n.next @ Subscriber.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:53
n._next @ filter.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:38
n.next @ Subscriber.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:53
n.next @ Subject.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:47
n.next @ ngxs-store.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:966
(anonymous) @ ngxs-store.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1280
(anonymous) @ ngxs-store.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1070
t.dispatchSingle @ ngxs-store.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1263
t.dispatchByEvents @ ngxs-store.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1244
(anonymous) @ ngxs-store.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1208
t.invoke @ zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:391
e.run @ zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:150
t.runOutsideAngular @ core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:26215
t.runOutsideAngular @ ngxs-store.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:79
t.enter @ ngxs-store.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:32
t.enter @ ngxs-store.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:826
t.dispatch @ ngxs-store.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1204
dispatch @ ngxs-store.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1578
t.dispatch @ ngxs-store.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:2549
(anonymous) @ link-preview-container.component.ts:117
n.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:192
n.next @ Subscriber.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:130
n._next @ Subscriber.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:76
n.next @ Subscriber.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:53
n.next @ Subject.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:47
(anonymous) @ preview-container.component.ts:33
o @ core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:23747
n.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:192
n.next @ Subscriber.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:130
n._next @ Subscriber.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:76
n.next @ Subscriber.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:53
n.next @ Subject.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:47
n.emit @ core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:23719
t.startDownload @ firefile-preview.component.ts:282
t.handleSuccess @ firefile-preview.component.ts:391
(anonymous) @ firefile-preview.component.ngfactory.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:62
handleEvent @ core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:29239
handleEvent @ core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:29784
Yr @ core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:19859
(anonymous) @ core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:21044
o @ core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:23747
n.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:192
n.next @ Subscriber.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:130
n._next @ Subscriber.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:76
n.next @ Subscriber.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:53
n.next @ Subject.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:47
n.handleCallback @ ngx-captcha.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:265
(anonymous) @ ngx-captcha.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:737
t.invoke @ zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:391
onInvoke @ core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:26256
t.invoke @ zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:390
e.run @ zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:150
t.run @ core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:26170
callback @ ngx-captcha.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:734
Le.X @ recaptcha__en.js:937
(anonymous) @ recaptcha__en.js:339
t.invoke @ zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:391
e.run @ zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:150
(anonymous) @ zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:910
t.invokeTask @ zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:423
e.runTask @ zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:195
g @ zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:601
e.invokeTask @ zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:502
l @ zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1693
h @ zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:1719
zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:199 

Uncaught n {headers: t, status: 500, statusText: 'OK', url: 'https://firefile.cc/secure/uploads/downloadChunk?<...>', ok: false, …}

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'onmessage')
    at Object.start (sw.js:53:22)
    at createStream (sw.js:50:10)
    at sw.js:41:19
start @ sw.js:53
createStream @ sw.js:50
(anonymous) @ sw.js:41
```

---

Summary:

I tried to download a file on firefile.cc and was expecting it to download like every previous time and every website do.

Just got the notification that only appear when downloading and it didn't download (didn't even got the "downloading" on the button)

Comment: I wanted to put a firefile tag but I have no reputation so I can't create it and I can't use it.